# How to invoke methods of a class where each method has different arguments at run time using java reflections?

Tags: java, reflection

I am working on a keyword driven framework for selenium.
I have written my methods in a separate class.
The following is the class that contains action methods for opening home page, entering username and password and clicking on the login button.

```
package actions;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class adminlogin {
    WebDriver driver;
    public adminlogin(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void adminopenhomepage() {
        driver.get("http://localhost/carrental/admin/");
    }
    public void adminenterusername(WebElement username) {
        username.sendKeys("admin");
    }
    public void adminenterpassword(WebElement password) {
        password.sendKeys("Test@12345");
    }
    public void adminclickloginbutton(WebElement loginbutton) {
        loginbutton.click();
    }
    public void adminclosebrowser() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I have the keywords in a list and I iterate through the keywords and call the above methods using reflections.
One way I would like to do is get the parameter types and number of parameters at runtime so that I can pass the parameters accordingly. I am trying to get the method using getDeclaredMethod(keyword) but this is working only for those methods that don't have parameters like adminopenhomepage() and giving exception no such method for all others as they accept parameters. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

```
for(String str : originalkeywords) {
    String keyword = str;
    String actioncl = keywordvsac.get(keyword);
    String objectcl = keywordvsor.get(keyword);

    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("actions."+actioncl);
    Method methodcall = cls.getDeclaredMethod(keyword);

    Parameter[] parameters = methodcall.getParameters();        
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parameters));
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated: read about Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. And you already named the class Admin... So why do you keep repeating that string in all of the method names? Method names go camelCase btw.

Comment: Ok, I will change the class name as per conventions. Not sure what you are saying about the method names. The method names are given as per the role that does the actions. If it is user I will name them as useropenhomepage etc. Not sure what you are saying. Do you have any solution for the question I am asking?

Comment: The code you are showing does not call exceptions? I think you should read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a method by reflection, you need three things:

1. class name of the object
2. class instance for which invoke the method
3. methods parameters.

Taking directly an example from [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html), to invoke a method just write:

```
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
    Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class };
    Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);
    String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length);
    System.out.format("invoking %s.main()%n", c.getName());
    main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);
```

To display the parameter names, just consult [another page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) of java official documentation, that talk about it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can simplify this code by just using `c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);`. Then, declaring `mainArgs` with type `Object` in the first place makes the subsequent type cast obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AdminLogin.class.getDeclaredMethods()` and use for loop to map all methods to some actions, as then you can read parameters using `method.getParameters()` but note that parameters might not have a name - this must be enabled in compiler using `-parameters` flag.

Proof of concept:

```
Map<String, Callable> mappedMethods = new HashMap<>(); // you can use runnable etc, I used callable as I don't want to catch exceptions in this example code - you should.
AdminLogin instance = new AdminLogin();
WebElement usernameElement = null; // idk how you get instance of this
WebElement passwordElement = null; // idk how you get instance of this
for (Method method : AdminLogin.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
   Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
   Object[] args = new Object[parameters.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
       Parameter parameter = parameters[i];
       if ((parameter.getType() == WebElement.class) && parameter.getName().equals("username")) {
           args[i] = usernameElement;
       }
       else if ((parameter.getType() == WebElement.class) && parameter.getName().equals("password")) {
           args[i] = passwordElement;
       } else {
           // log some info/throw exception, whatever you need for methods that can't be mapped
           break;
       }
   }
   mappedMethods.put(method.getName(), () -> method.invoke(instance, args));
}
```

And now you can just call that callables by name from map.

But note that you should add more abstraction here, as such wall of ifs if you have more argument types to handle or duplicating this code for each class will be a bad idea.
Also read about annotations in java, they are useful to mark special methods and parameters like that, but don't overuse them too.

Also note that `getDeclaredMethods` returns methods in no particular order, and for sure not in same order as declared one in class.